# Is there any limit on number of classes that a namespace can have in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Is there any limit on number of classes that a namespace can have in .NET? Further what is the recommended number of classes that there should be in a namespace?

Comment: Why are you asking?... My money is on there being no limit, and no recommended number.  It depends on your project.

Comment: I was asked this question in a technical interview.

Comment: See also [Ideal number of classes per namespace branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146316/ideal-number-of-classes-per-namespace-branch)

Comment: My guess is that the interviewer simply wants to gauge if you have basic knowledge of .NET code encapsulation. If you try to give an actual number as an answer (unless, of course, you *know* the actual number), it shows that you're missing the point that the number of classes that a namespace can have is likely inconsequential and less important than simply knowing how to encapsulate your code well. At least, *I hope* that's what the interviewer was going for. I'm not sure I'd want to work for someone who expected an actual numeric answer to that question.

Comment: @Ben I too was surprised at the question. I simply replied that to my knowledge there is no limit set. To this the interviewer replied there exists a limit.. check for yourself.  So i posted the question here. And looking at all the replies it seems i was right.

Comment: @Hot Perhaps he/she was trying to get you to push back to ask, if indeed there is a limit, why it even matters.  I enjoy pushing back at senior devs, not to question authority, but because it helps me to better understand software development.  I really value a workplace where questions are encouraged and will even try to feel out in an interview if I'm going to have that kind of relationship with those for whom I'll be working.

Comment: Great self promotion of your own answer @Constantin!

Comment: @Daniel Dyson: Arghhh, you exposed my sneaky rep-whoring tactics! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tried it out: I just built an assembly containing 1,000,000 types in the same namespace without any problem. However at 5,000,000 the C# compiler ran out of memory.

Comment: @Stevan... so one can say that there is no limit to number of classes that a namespace can have... but there are memory constraint that can effect it.

Comment: @HotTester: I believe it can. Assume the C# compiler didn't crash and produced one gigantic dll. The CLR must still be able to load types in memory. The CLR does this lazy but, all used classes will stay JITted in memory till the process dies. However, it is very hard to count this in number of classes, because normally classes will be much bigger than the empty `class C { }` types I compiled in my experiment. btw, we perhaps could determine the maximum number of types in an assembly, but because a single namespace is not limited to a single assembly, this amount would be practically unlimited

Comment: I choose this as answer as Stevan actually implemented it for verification. Thanks Stevan for the efforts. If any new findings come up do share with all.

Comment: You can create millions of assemblies containing classes in the same namespace. The limit only seems to be practical (compiler memory, disk space, runtime memory)

Comment: why assembly? the question in on namespaces..

Comment: @toto': an assembly is a compilation unit. As class names must be unique within a namespace, using the maximum length of a class name and the allowed characters, you can calculate the theoretical maximum number of classes (about 1.0E+4811) in a single namespace (within a single assembly), but it makes little sense if it can't be compiled. That's why I tested what could actually be compiled. But as others in this thread noted, you can repeat this process by creating additional assemblies with the same number of classes. But at any point memory will be your limiting factor.

Answer (score 30):

There's no specified maximum number of classes "per namespace"-- a namespace is really just a part of the Type's full name, not a logical entity in the CLR

The recommended number is whatever makes sense:  use namespaces to group logically related classes together.

I'm sure that if you have enough types you can run the compiler or the runtime out of memory, but that's a physical limit not a specification - and it probably doesn't matter if they are in the same namespace or not.

Note that as Steven points out, you can also have the same namespace present in multiple assemblies as well.

Comment: Don't forget that while there could be a maximum number of types per assembly, a single namespace could be spread over an unlimited number of assemblies, making the number of types in that namespace practically unlimited.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure this will get buried, but there is a VERY finite number of classes you can have in a dll. [This source](http://eusebium.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-many-classes-can-single-net-dll.html) says that

> If a class is identified in the metadata table using a metadata token and the metadata token is a four-byte number, this means that the number of classes that an assembly can contain is smaller than the biggest number on 3 bytes (the first byte is a connection to the metadata table type). The biggest number on 3 bytes is 2^24– 1 or 16777215.
>
> Therefore, the maximum number of classes (and classes members) that a .NET assembly can contain is 16777215.

Comment: I don't understand all the "no limit" answers with upvotes. How do people think classes are referenced after being JITed? This is the correct answer.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski: The original question asked about the number of classes in a *namespace*. This answer makes a statement about the number of types in an *assembly*. While technically correct, this answers a different question. The "no theoretical limit" answers are more to the point, and equally correct.

Comment: @stakx The question didn't ask about a theoretical limit, but for the record 16777215 IS the theoretical limit based on the CLI spec. The practical limit is however much memory you have up to that point. This answer in practice is the only one that matters. From the question it is unclear whether he wanted to know just for fun or because he had to make a design decision based on how many classes he could have, in which case this is the answer he is looking for.

Comment: @Mike Marynowski: Just for reference, could you please mention the ECMA-335 chapter number where the maximum number of runtime types is stated for any CLI implementation?

Comment: @stakx I don't have time to look through it to find it but in Partition II where it breaks down the metadata token format it explains that the last 3 bytes of the 4 byte token are for identifying the object and you can also deduce this limitation from the fact that all the metadata related IL instructions only have a 4 byte metadata token as arguments.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no such limit, in the same way that there is no limit to the number of classes you can have.

The namespace is simply part of the full name of the class.

Answer (score 3):

No limit. The feasabe number of types depends on the problem domain. If a certain "folder" as many types you have any freedom. In my application I have a namespace for messages in a certain protocol and I have around 200 different message types.

Answer (score 3):

There may or may not be a physical limit, but you should reach a logical limit well before getting there.

As for "how many should there be," the answer, like most in .Net, is "it depends."  There is no clear-cut answer to that - basically, you want to logically divide your solution into projects related by functionality or purpose - whatever makes sense in your particular case, and for your particular tastes.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a new assembly with more classes in any given namespace. No compiler can practically enforce a global limit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a class name has to fit into a string. There are only some valid characters, so giving that as a very rough guess as 850000 because I can't be bothered getting a count of the characters in different classes in the UCS, this would - in a namespace of one character-length name - give a limit of 850000x10737418213!x10737418213!. However, VB.NET can only work with names of 1023 characters in size, so that would limit it to 850000x1021!x1021! and C# can only handle 511 character long names, so 85000x509!x509!

I haven't a .NET4.0 framework, so the big-numeric math needed to work those equations out is too compliated to bother with right now ;)

The 85000 is probably well off, but ideographic characters are generally in the Lo class, which is allowed in class names, and they fill out a very large chunk of the assigned code-points. In any case, this whatever the real value is will increase with later Unicode versions.

All manner of technical and even physical limits will be hit before this point anyway, but way, way before then we hit the purposeful limit. The namespace doesn't exist for the compiler, it exist for the humans. The compiler could deal just as well (indeed, perhaps better) if there were no namespaces and coders just guaranteed never to reuse names. Namespaces exist for human beings to have reasonably-sized (learnably sized) groups of types to deal with.

Comment: It's evening chill-out time in my timezone. Besides, if it were a really slow day, I would have gotten an exact count of valid name-start and name-part characters and done this much more accurately.

Comment: For those interested, Wolfram Alpha reports that 850000x509!x509! is only 2323 decimal digits long :)

Comment: So you would only have needed to be creating around 10E+2293 or so names a picosecond since the Big Bang to be in danger of hitting this limit some time soon. Such code clearly should have been refactored about 2billion years ago.