# Are hash codes of System.Type objects of types from the same assembly guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hash

**Clarifying edit**: The keys in the dictionary are actual instances of `System.Type`. More specifically every value is stored with its type as the key.

In a specific part of my program the usage of `Dictionary<System.Type, SomeThing>` takes a large chunk of CPU time, as per Visual Studio 2017 performance profiler.

A change in the type of the dictionary to `Dictionary<int, SomeThing>` and instead of passing the type object directly I pass the `type.GetHashCode()` seems to be about 20%-25% faster.

The above optimization will result in a nasty bug if two types have the same hash code, but it seems plausible to me that types can have unique hash codes, at least when it comes to types from the same assembly - which all the types used in this dictionary are.

Possibly relevant information - As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404544/940723) the number of possible types in an assembly is far smaller than the number of values represented by `System.Int32`.

Comment: Hash codes aren't meant to be used for identity, and are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: They are just ment to be *unique enough* to be found fast. You could even write a hash-code that allways returns `1`.

Comment: I think that by the time you override everything required to guarantee that this works, it will burn your savings and then some.  It's a simple matter of probabilities, even the lowest probabilities happen now and then, maybe the very next time you try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The documentation [on `object.GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.1) make no guarantees, and states:

> A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in collections that are based on a hash table. A hash code is not a permanent value. For this reason:
>
> ...
>
> - Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a keyed collection.

Because equal hash codes is necessary, but not sufficient, for two objects to be equal.

If you're wondering if `Type.GetHashCode()` follows a more restrictive definition, [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Type_GetHashCode) makes no mention of such a change, so it still does not guarantee uniqueness. The [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,e8937d5bb4bb6af3) does not show any attempt to make this guarantee, either.

Comment: I only care about the implementation of `GetHashCode` in `System.Type`.

Comment: As mentioned, that implementation (and the documentation thereof) do not make this guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

A hash-code is never garantueed to be unique for different values, so you should not use it like you are doing.
The same value should however generate the same hashcode.

This is also stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes.

and somewhat further:

> Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a keyed collection.

Therefore, I would also not rely for GetHashCode for different types to be unique, but at least, you can verify it:

```
Dictionary<int, string> s = new Dictionary<int, string>();

var types = typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes();

Console.WriteLine($"Inspecting {types.Length} types...");

foreach (var t in typeof(-put a type from that assembly here-).Assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (s.ContainsKey(t.GetHashCode()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name} has the same hashcode as {s[t.GetHashCode()]}");
    }
    else
    {
        s.Add(t.GetHashCode(), t.Name);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("done!");
```

But even if the above test would conclude that there are no collisions, I wouldn't do it, since the implementation of GetHashCode can change over time, which means that collisions in the future might be possible.

Comment: It is obviously possible to create a set of classes and ensure they have unique hash codes and that is what I'm asking about here.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that :)

Comment: @Acidic, it is also possible to have classes that ensure they do **not** have unique hash codes. How do we know you're not talking about those? There is nothing in your question to make us conclude your class instances have unique hash codes.

Comment: @Acidic you can definitely override `GetHashCode` for each of the types in your assembly and provide suitably unique values if that's what you need.  In fact, that's what you have to do when you create simple types anyway.

Comment: @Acidic Sure it is, but that´s not how `GetHashCode` is implemented . at least for `Type`. But you shouldn´t care for that too much.

Comment: @DourHighArch I am asking specifically about `System.Type` objects. I've edited the question to make it more obvious.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well it's potentially a substantial performance boost in an important part of my application, so I definitely care about it.

Comment: @Acidic Performance is irrelevant when the behavior is different.  Only one solution works.

Comment: @Servy And that is precisely why I asked this question, to find out if the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Acidic A question which the documentation would have answered for you with a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

A hashcode isn´t ment do be unique. Instead it is used in hash-based collections such as `Dictionary` in order to *limit* the number of possible ambiguities. A hashc-ode is nothing but an index, so instead of searching the entire collection for a match only a few items that share a common value - the hash-code - have to be considered.

In fact you could even have a hash-implementation that allways returns the same number for every item. However that´ll leads to O(n) to look for a key in your dictionary, as every key has to be compared.

Anyway you shouldn´t strive for micro-optimizations that get you some nan-seconds in exchange for maintainability and understandability. You should instead use some data-structure that gets the job done and is easy to understand.

Comment: I'm not asking if hash codes are unique in general, only if they are unique for types (or at least types in the same assembly). It is obviously possible to implemented the `GetHashCode` method to return unique hash codes if the number of objects is relatively small.